# Mapping one-to-many Relationship in GGTS

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, one-to-many, ggts

I'm new and self learning, so please bear with me...

I've racked my brain for days on this error I'm getting when trying to map a one-to-many relationship between my Personnel class and my Probdata class in GGTS.

Here are some code snippets:

```
package benefitsapplication
```

class Personnel {

```
static hasMany = [probations:Probdata,probterms:Probdata]
static mappedBy =  [probations:"lineNumber", probterms:"paysrId"]
```

//  static hasMany = [probations:Probdata]
//  static mappedBy =  [probations:"lineNumber"]

```
String lineNumber
String paysrId
    ....


package benefitsapplication
```

class Probdata {

```
static belongsTo = [person:Personnel]


String lineNumber
String reportNumber
String paysrId
    ...
```

I tried mapping using 2 objects (composite key) at first, then tried using one. Each time, I get the same error:

"Error loading plugin manager: Non-existent mapping property [lineNumber] specified for property [probations] in class [benefitsapplication.Personnel]"

Then GGTS says to use --stacktrace for details (which I have no clue where that is or how to run it)

Based off of my own research, which none of my books cover, the Mapping() method is always used to map between classes, but the MappedBy() method isn't necessarily used.

Is that, in short, what I'm missing? The Mapping() method? And should I also put it in the child table? Or not necessarily? Do I need the MappedBy() method?

Related question - Initially, I used my "Probations" identifier for both objects. In my trying to troubleshoot, I changed that. Does that even matter?

Answer (score 0):

So I posed this question in a forum run by the publishers of the Grails in Action book. The author responded and was very helpful.

He explained that MappedBy() and Mapping() methods deal with specifically mapping objects within **domain** classes of the same class type. For instance, if I had 2 objects of type Personnel.

MappedBy() and Mapping() do not apply to objects of String type, which are not domain type classes.